Special elliptic pencil of an Enriques surface (arguments in a proof)
I have a couple of questions about arguments in the proof of Lemma 2.6 (see absol page 199, rel p 9) from Shigeyuki Kondo's paper Enriques surfaces with finite automorphism groups:
The setup: Let $Y$ be a complex Enriques surface $Y$,  so in following we work in complex setting, ie $Y$ is aspecially a compact (in modern terms proper) complex smooth surface.

LEMMA (2.6). Let $\pi: Y \to \Bbb P^1$ be a special elliptic pencil of an Enriques surface $Y$. (Ie, the general fiber of $\pi$ is smooth elliptic and special means that it has a $2$-section $R$ which is nodal curve (see Def 2.4 in the linked paper). Let $X$ be the  $K3$ surface coming as double cover of $Y$ and $\sigma: X \to X$ its covering involution. Denoted by $\widetilde{\pi}: X \to \Bbb P^1$ the base change of $\pi: Y \to \Bbb P^1$. (BTW: This map is called "base change", but bc along what? Isn't this just the composition $\pi \circ p$? Or it there tacitly an involution of $\Bbb P^1$ involved?) Then there is an elliptic pencil $J(\pi): J(Y) \to \Bbb P^1$ which satisfying certain conditions (i),(ii),(iii),(iv) given in the linked paper.

I struggle with several steps in the presented proof. Could somebody look through if one or other point can be resolved:
(A): What is the argument that the inverse image $p^{-1}(R)$ of the $2$-section $R$ of $Y$ - which exists as $Y$ special - is given by a disjoint union of two nodal curves $R_+,R_-$ (here: nodal curve = smooth rational curve, ie $\Bbb P^1$; older terminology, see p 196).
Intuitivelly: Why the double cover $p:X \to Y$ resolves "doubleness" of the $2$-section $2$? In other words $R_+,R_-$ become honest sections of $X \to \Bbb P^1$.
(B): Assuming (A) has been resolved, why there exist automorphism $t: X \to X$ defined as $t(x):=r^+(\widetilde{\pi}(x)-r^-(\widetilde{\pi}(x)$ where $r^+, r^-: \Bbb P^1 \to X$ corresp to honnest sections $R_+,R_-$ from previous part. Note, that $"-"$ should come from fibrewise group structure.
Intuitivelly, this should correspond to a flip of $R_+$ and $R_-$.
I mean, there are strictly speaking two potential problems with this construction: Firstly, since $\pi: Y \to \Bbb P^1$ is elliptic pencil, only the general, but not every fibre of $\pi$ is elliptic curve - so has group structure - but does also the general fibre of  $\widetilde{\pi}= \pi \circ p: X \to \Bbb P^1$ inherit group structure, recall $p:X \to Y$ is double cover?
Furthermore, assume we can manage the first problem, what about the fibres, which are not elliptic curves - so carry no group structure? There the minus $"-"$ in def. of $t$ seemingly don't make sense. Or, can one invoke there some extension result?
(C): Later one manages to construct an involution $\tau: X \to X$ and set $S =X/ \langle \tau \rangle $. Is it clear that $S$ admits elliptic pencil induced from $\widetilde{\pi}$? The thing is, $X$ is branched $2$-cover of $S$. General fibre $X_b= \widetilde{\pi}^{-1}(b)$ of $\widetilde{\pi}$ is an elliptic curve , is the quotient $S_b =X_b/ \langle \tau \rangle $ of such general fibre still elliptic curve?
(D): Next one introduces $J(\pi):J(Y) \to \Bbb P^1$ as minimal model of the pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$ from prev. Q (C). Is it clear why the anticanonical linear system $\vert -K_{J(Y)} \vert $ must contain a fibre of $J(\pi)$? From what does it follow?

The "branched double cover $p:X\rightarrow Y$" is not branched.

@abx: Right, thanks, so its a honnest etale map

Think it's standard, but let me add discussion in I, 18 in Barth's Compact Complex Surfaces adressing this point that the existence of such etale double cover is indicated by existence of $2$-torsion in integral homology. To translate it to algebro geometric context one can find $2$-torsion in Picard group of $Y$, from this there is a machinery to construct cyclic covers, see also Chap 17

So, this settles (A). For (B), note that a birational automorphism of a K3 surface is actually biregular.

@abx: Not sure why this implies (A): clearly this implies that $p$ would restrict to an etale $2$-cover $p \vert R: p^{-1}(R) \to R$ (base change of etale stays etale) over this $2$-section $R \subset Y$, but it is claimed that $p^{-1}(R)$ is disjoint union of components $R+$ and $R_-$, which are sections. Why $p^{-1}(R)$ cannot be a connected cover? My guess is that there might something fishy intersection of $p^{-1}(R)$ with general fibre if we would assume it to be connected, but not sure

@abx: Ad (B): Is this extendability statement birational map to biregular maps a special feature of K3 surfaces (...could you recomend a source adressing this point) or is it a more general statement about proper smooth surfaces? With properness & smoothness we can always extend such birational map $X \to X$ of smth proper surf to codim  $1$ points using valuative crit of properness, but how we get regulatity everywhere?

@abx: Or, on point (B), I think that what you wrote about extendability of birat to biregular map follows from general properties of relative minimal models, right?

@abx: Maybe an update solving the issue with (A): Do we know that $R$ is isomorphic to a line, ie $\cong \Bbb P^1$? (Then it cannot have nontriv connected covers and this would indeed solve (A); but I not see any reason why this should be the case)

For (A): you say yourself that $R\cong \mathbb{P}^1$. And  indeed,  (B) follows from  basic properties of minimal surfaces.

@abx: Ad (A), ah right, that $2$-section $R = \Bbb P^1$ (="nodal" in Kondo's terms) was part def to be special ellpt pencil. Do you maybe have an idea on (D) why the linear system of anticanonical sheaf of $J(Y)$ includes a fibre divisor? $J(Y) $ is choosen the be a minimal model of pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$...does it probably follow somehow from general theory of min models? Dont know, just a guess

$J(Y)$ is $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at the 9 base points of a pencil of cubic curves, so $\lvert -K_{J(Y)}\rvert$ consists of the fibers of this pencil. No offense, but I think you should start by reading some basic introduction to surfaces.

@abx: sorry for persistent questioning things which maybe with a bit more background of that topic appear trivial, but I not understand this part, more presicely I not see the direct connection to $S$. The surface you constructed is is surely minimal (no $-1$-curves), but the way you constructed I not see the direct relation to initial pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$ we started with. Going a step back there should be given a map for $S$ to it. Could you maybe clarify this? Eg. why you started with pencil of cubics of $P^2$?

@abx: let me maybe clarify the the point of my confusion: In the quoted paper $J(Y)$ is introduced not as minimal model of $S$ in absulute sense (...with this topic I'm basically familar with), but minimal model of the pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$, so in relative setting, and I doubt that basic literature treating theory of minimal models for surfaces discuss it and especially methods how to construct one, uniqueness issues, which are partially known in "absolute" case. Your aproach appears a to be "add hoc", you construct indeed a relative minimal model, but the problem is that I not see

why it should actually be minimal model of the pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$, so in relative sense. So we need assure that there exist a map $S \to J(Y)$ which additionally have to respect pencil structure to $\Bbb P^1$. Could you maybe elaborate this part? I doubt that this relative case is really basic, or could you recommend maybe sources adressing exactly this issue?

Sorry, I have to stop here. I haven't read the paper and I don't have time to read it. Good luck!

@abx: No problem, thanks for your time! (Maybe just one point - once you could borrow some time - could you maybe briefly skim through: So your blowup $B$ construction you proposed is (1) clearly minimal as abstr surf (2) seems to be birational to given $S$ (...here I'm not sure, it is obtained as blowup of $\Bbb P^2$, so rational, on the other hnd function fld $K(S)$ coinsides with fction field $K(E)$ of generic fibre of $S \to P^1$, an ellipt curve $E$ over $K(P^1)$. Is it rational?)...lets say its ok, then forgetting pencil

we get that $B$ minimal model of $S$ abstractly, as every birat class of not ruled smth proper surf has unique minim model. So we get dominant map $S \to B$. But is it compatible with pencil datum, ie is it relative minimal mdl of ellipt pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$? Think that this is important detail...

I was just copying Lemma 2.6 of the paper.

@abx: Could you maybe sketch the argument why the constructed quotient surface $S =X/ \langle \tau \rangle$ in the proof is actually rational? (This would justify that the the blowup in $9$ pts of indeterminancy of the pencil of place cubics you contructed in prev comments is actually it's minimal model)
